# Outlook AutoDiscover giving internal address to external client

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2013

When trying to set up Exchange on my new Surface Pro, it gets the internal hostname of the internal Client Access server instead of the hostname of the public-facing CAS, and therefore fails to connect. I recently made some changes to my Exchange 2010 environment with regard to hostnames in order to resolve an issue with internal clients connecting to the wrong Client Access Server, but I thought I got rid of all references to the internal hostname! And now it is back. The problem is even if I manually change the hostname to the correct one in Outlook's Repair Account wizard, when I run a Check Name, it sets it back to the internal one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Outlook Anywhere works fine and sets the Internal CAS name when checking the name.  That's fine.

What you need is More Settings -> Connection -> Exchange Proxy Settings to populate with the External URL.  You probably need to run something like:

```
Enable-OutlookAnywhere -Server CAS01 -ExternalHostname "mail.contoso.com" -ExternalAuthenticationMethod "Basic" -SSLOffloading:$False
```

You can also set this through the GUI through the Configure External Client Access Domain wizard.

For more information, see [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd876959%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that gives me the following error:

The virtual directory 'Rpc' already exists under 'ServerName.example.ca/Default Web Site'.
Parameter name: VirtualDirectoryName
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (ServerName\Rpc (Default Web Site):ADObjectId) [Enable-OutlookAnywhere], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 78712C6B,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemConfigurationTasks.EnableRpcHttp

Comment: Interesting... After a reboot of the Exchange server, everything started working as it should. Thanks!